# Is this too much work for 1 listener?

Tags: java, android, event-handling

Is this too much work for 1 touch listener? Is this bad for devices with slow CPU's?

```
@Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch(id){
                      case R.id.sound1:
                          if(event.getAction()==android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){


                          if(intLoop ==0){
                              mp1=MediaPlayer.create(MainClass.this, R.raw.item1);
                              mp1.start();
                              v.setPressed(true);
                              return true;
                          }
                          if(intLoop == 1){
                              mp1=MediaPlayer.create(MainClass.this, R.raw.item1);
                              mp1.start();
                              mp1.setLooping(true);
                              v.setPressed(true);
                              return true;
                          }
                          }else if 
                              (event.getAction()==android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                              mp1.stop();
                              mp1.reset();
                              mp1.release();
                              v.setPressed(false);
                              clickCounter();
                              return false;
                              }                   
                         break;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dodging your question for a quick comment:

Why don't you combine these

```
                      if(intLoop ==0){
                          mp1=MediaPlayer.create(MainClass.this, R.raw.item1);
                          mp1.start();
                          v.setPressed(true);
                          return true;
                      }
                      if(intLoop == 1){
                          mp1=MediaPlayer.create(MainClass.this, R.raw.item1);
                          mp1.start();
                          mp1.setLooping(true);
                          v.setPressed(true);
                          return true;
                      }
```

into this?

```
                      mp1=MediaPlayer.create(MainClass.this, R.raw.item1);
                      mp1.start();
                      if(intLoop == 1){
                          mp1.setLooping(true);
                      }
                      v.setPressed(true);
                      return true;
```

And, as Vogel612 mentions, is there any reason `intLoop` is not a boolean?

I think that if the rest of your code looks like that, simply combining the functionality like this might fix the idea that the listener is doing a lot.

Comment: and why not put intLoop into what it is, a boolean, for that matter ;)

Comment: Damn @Vogel612 why so quick, I wanted to edit that in =/

Comment: Um well it used to be Boolean but I changed it to int for some reason, I thought it was better for performance, now on second look it doesn't make any sense..And yeah, it doesn't look like too much work now. Thanks Vogel612 and Pimgd

Answer (score 2):

You likely have a bug. if / if / else if will often trigger first if, and else if.

Update: your code is indented horribly. And that's crazy, you basically have a nested switch. Yes, way too obfuscated. Please fix.

int loop 0 and 1 only differ by one line of code. Just do them in common then

```
if(loop == 1) {
    // that one line of code that's different
}
```

You should be switching on event loop enum, which means, oh god, you have a three-layer switch.

In any case, mp1 basically has an "on" operation and an "off" operation. You should code these up - either add them to mp1's class, or create a new object, or simply write helper functions, etc. This will reduce your inner switch to a much simpler one-line on/off situation, which is very clear and a good use of switch. In general very few lines of code should happen in switches: they should be functions that do analogous actions, on the same level.

mp1 should be `final` I think.

Comment: Wow, didn't know it's that bad. Well thanks for your advice's, I will pay more attention on that.